# "wput" multiple files from command line?

Tags: command-line, ftp, wget, command-line-tool

You can upload a single file with `wput`:

```
wput file ftp://username:passwd@ipaddress/file
```

is there a way to upload multiple? Maybe something like:

```
wput {file1,file2} ftp://username:passwd@ipaddress/{file1,file2}
```

*Note*: I know there are solutions using `ftp`, `curl`, and others. I was wondering if there is one for `wput`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the manual:](http://wput.sourceforge.net/wput.1.html)

```
So you can specify e.g. one URL and read all filenames from a file. 
Or use wput *.txt ftp://host, to transfer all *.txt-files. 
See EXAMPLES for further examples.
```

> −i file
>
> −−input−file=file
>
> Reads URLs and filenames from file. If there are URLs on the
>   command-line too, these will be retrieved first, unless sorting is
>   enabled. See also the URL-Input-Handling section. If file is −, the
>   URLs will be read from stdin. If you want to pipe the contents of the
>   file that shall be uploaded to stdin, this cannot be done (yet). But
>   you can use the --input-pipe flag and read the contents a) from a
>   named pipe -I "cat named.pipe; echo > /dev/null" or b) directly from
>   the command, that outputs the data. (See --input-pipe) Do not do
>   things like find | wput `ftp://host/` −i −! Wput would upload all files
>   from the current directory (since the first output of find will be
>   ’.’) and afterwards each file again (since find postes its name to
>   Wput. And further problematic is that Wput will upload each directory
>   that is given by find and since find itself recurses all directories,
>   the files would be uploaded three times (or even more often for
>   further subdirectories). Use wput `ftp://host/` to upload everything
>   from the local directory. Or use find ! −type d | wput `ftp://host/` −i
>   − to tell find, not to output directories.